# Get Minecraft server data in python

Tags: python, minecraft

i have Ubuntu Server machine running Minecraft Server to play with my friends and stuff, but i am bored and i want to make simple python app in console to display server status, like current number of connected players, difficulty, world seed, RAM used and stuff... my question is, if its possible to get this data from MC server application, and if then how. Mainly i am interested about live player data (count, names, probably posotion), chat feed etc.. I didn´t tried anything because i have no idea where to start :D
thanks
-N

Comment: I am afraid this question is too vague, you might want to go to a forum for a better discussion about the topic.

Comment: Actually not, already answered. And its pretty simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you were looking for something like this:
https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus

Edit:

The module is named "mcstatus" and provides a "A Python class for checking the status of an enabled Minecraft server".

You can install it via pip: `pip install mcstatus`

It provides three modes of access (query, status and ping), the differences of which are listed on the page of this link.

Comment: EXACTLY! Many thanks, its awesome and simple <3

Comment: Doesn't work...